# Creating floats from binary value in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to modify bit values of float variables. To do this, I am using the struct package to acquire the binary values of a float as a string, like so:

```
num = -5.661166216897089
s = struct.pack('!f', num)
b = ''.join(format(c, '08b')for c in s)
```

I will then modify the desired bits with splicing. My question is:

After modifying the string of bits as needed, how can I use it to create a new float value with the modified bit sequence? Defining it as such:

```
new_float = 0b11000000101101010010100001000110
```

does not work, I suspect as it is being interpreted as an integer. Is there a way to force float creation?

Thanks ^^

Comment: The key is that you use `struct.unpack` to undo what you did with `struct.pack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `b` you create a new `str`, `v` by changing some bits of `b`. For example:

```py
v='11001110101101010010100001000110'
```

Now, you can convert that to bytes:

```py
v_bytes = bytes([int(v[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(4)])
```

Which looks like:

```py
print(v_bytes)
b'\xce\x9d:u'
```

and that can be given to `struct.unpack`:

```py
new_num = struct.unpack("!f", v_bytes)[0]
```

`unpack` returns a tuple, that's why you must take its first element with `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an integer to convert the bits to bytes and then struct.unformat to get the new float back.

```
num = -5.661166216897089
s = struct.pack('!f', num)
b = f'{int.from_bytes(s,"big"):032b}'

new_float, = struct.unpack('!f',int(b,2).to_bytes(4,'big'))
print(new_float)
-5.661166191101074
```

The problem with this is that Python's floats are actually 8 byte (64 bits) doubles. So `num = -5.661166216897089` is stored with more precision than its 4 byte representation would allow.  This is why converting the 32 bit representation back to a float doesn't give the original value.

*If your original number is an actual 4 byte float (e.g. -5.661166191101074), then it will come out correctly despite Python internally storing it as a double)*.

If you do this with an 8 byte representation (double), you will get the original value as expected:

```
num = -5.661166216897089
s = struct.pack('!d', num)
b = f'{int.from_bytes(s,"big"):064b}'

print(b)
1100000000010110101001010000100011000001101110110010110000010011

new_float, = struct.unpack('!d',int(b,2).to_bytes(8,'big'))
print(new_float)
-5.661166216897089
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own code to convert the bits to a float using the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format):

- The first (most significant) bit is the `sign`
- The next eight bits are the `exponent`
- The next 23 bits form the fractional part

This results in the following calculation for the value of the floating-point number:

```
value = -1**sign * 2**(exponent - 127) * fraction
```

where `fraction` is 1 plus the summation of `bits[23 - i] * 2**-i` for `i` in `range(1, 24)`. Note that `bits[0]` is the *least significant bit*.

```
fraction_bits = b[-1:-24:-1] # reverse fraction bits so least significant bit is at [0]

fraction = 1
for i in range(1, 24):
    fraction += 2**-i * int(fraction_bits[23 - i])
```

Constructing `value` using the formula given above yields the expected `value = -5.661166191101074` (accounting for the loss in precision due to the 32-bit float as mentioned by [Alain T.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034710/843953)):

```
sign = int(b[0])
exponent = int(b[1:9], base=2)

value = -1**sign * 2**(exponent - 127) * fraction
```

---

To handle 64-bit double-precision floats, you'll need to implement [that instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

- The most significant bit is still the `sign`.
- The next *eleven* bits are the `exponent`.
- The last *52* bits are the fractional part.

In this case, we have

```
value = -1**sign * 2**(exponent - 1023) * fraction
```

where `fraction` is 1 plus the summation of `bits[52 - i] * 2**-i` for `i` in `range(1, 53)`. Implementing these changes to the 32-bit version, and using the 64-bit representation of `num = -5.661166216897089` as `b = '1100000000010110101001010000100011000001101110110010110000010011'`, we get `value = -5.661166216897089`